# Communicating two tabs on two devices in javascript using broadcast channel

Tags: javascript, html, broadcast-channel

I need some advice on whether I need to reimplement my project or I can make the current implementation work. I have implemented a user interface to do some wizard of oz testing. I have a user-side page (Page A), which fires up a second page, the wizard page (Page B). When the user asks questions on page A, the question is sent to page B using a broadcast channel, and the answer is received through a broadcast channel. Everything works great on the same computer.

But my problem is that I want to open the wizard page on a second device, so the user doesn't see the wizard is answering the user's question. When I open the wizard page on a second device (my first device is an apple MacBook, and my second device also is an apple MacBook), the communication between the two pages doesn't happen. Both pages are located on the same server and have the same host name.

Is there any way I can make my current implementation work on two devices?
Or should I just re-implement the communication part?

I would very much appreciate any solution or hint.

Comment: https://webrtc.org/